# Get bash output with python

Tags: python, bash, sublimetext2, subprocess

I'm trying to make a simple command that will let me run bash fully in Python, including output strings.

This function worked great on systems I use at my job:

```
import subprocess

def run(command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    return output
```

However, now I'm using it at home and the PATH variable doesn't match the one in my Terminal.

So when I execute

```
run('ls')
```

I get this:

```
/bin/sh: ls: command not found
```

Which makes sense because, nonsensically, the PATH I get from running

```
print run('/usr/bin/env')
```

is

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/
```

Now, I could remedy all this by using:

```
run('/bin/ls')
```

But that defeats the entire purpose of using this command, which is to faithfully emulate the `bash` shell.

**How do I make run() use the system's PATH or create an equivalent function that just works?**

(No platitudes about the dangers of using `'shell=True'`, please. This is all personal use with innocuous commands like `ls` and `ps axw`.)

Comment: The plumbum (http://plumbum.readthedocs.org) library source might be helpful.

Comment: What does `os.getenv('PATH')` return, both at work and at home, in the python process?

Comment: At home, it is the ridiculous `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/
` listed above. At work, it is the more sensible `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/software/dist/admin/bin:/opt/www/htdig/bin:/usr/lib/java/bin:/usr/lib/java/jre/bin:/usr/share/texmf/bin`

Comment: I'm running the Python script from within Sublime Text 2. I think this is relevant because I get a better path at home from the `python` executable running `os.getenv('PATH')`.

Comment: Yes. That is it. The command runs fine in the Terminal with `python <script>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving this question up because I think the `run()` command above is useful and I couldn't find anything similar on SO.

However, my solution was very system specific. The problem was, I am running this script within Sublime Text 2 and had manually replaced the path in `Python.sublime-settings` with

```
"path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/",
```

I did this because I'd had problems getting ST2 to find the right version of `python`. Well, this also overwrites the system-wide PATH variable within ST2, thus blocking my access to simple shell programs like `ls`.

Erasing the `"path": ...` line from `Python.sublime-settings` fixed my problem.

**EDIT**

As [suggested by mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183924/get-bash-output-with-python/23184244#comment35458820_23184244), changing the line to *append* the path works as well:

```
"path": "$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/",
```

Comment: To _append to_ the existing `$PATH`, use `"path": "$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/"`.