# Get all output of bash command in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line

I have a Python scrit which let me to check PHP file syntax.

I use **subprocess.check_output** command to call a bash command but it returns me only half of the response displayed.

The **check_php.py** file :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding:utf-8
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import argparse
import fnmatch
import ntpath

path_base = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="This command checks the PHP syntaxe of files"
)
parser.add_argument('--path', '-p',
    help="Path for .php searching"
)
parser.add_argument('--file', '-f',
    help="Path of file to check"
)
args = parser.parse_args()

def check_php_file(path_file):
    command = 'php -l '+path_file
    sortie = ''
    try:
        sortie = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    except Exception as e:
        sortie = str(e)
    return sortie

if args.path:
    if args.path.startswith('/') or args.path.startswith('~'):
        path_base = args.path
    else:
        path_base = os.path.join(path_base, args.path)

if args.file:
    if args.file.startswith('/') or args.file.startswith('~'):
        path_file = args.path
    else:
        path_file = os.path.join(path_base, args.file)
    response = check_php_file(path_file)
    print("_____"+response+"_____")
```

The **checking.php** file (with a syntax error) :

```
<?php
if (true {
    echo "True";
}
```

The command to check PHP file :

```
python check_php.py -f checking.php
```

The output displayed after command :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/jedema/checking.php on line 3
_____Command 'php -l /home/jedema/checking.php' returned non-zero exit status 255_____
```

So, my Python code can handle the following response :

```
Command 'php -l /home/jedema/checking.php' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

But I want also get in a String the following response :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/jedema/checking.php on line 3
```

Do you have any idea to get the full response ?

*Edit I have already read the following question : [Get bash output with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183924/get-bash-output-with-python)*

### Solution (inspired by Salo answer)

Install [Sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) :

```
pip install sh
```

It works by adding these imports :

```
import sh
```

Then, With this check_php_file_method :

```
def check_php_file(path_file):
    sortie = ''
    try:
        sortie = sh.php('-l', path_file)
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode_255 as e:
        sortie = format(e.stderr)
    return sortie
```

Comment: You are getting

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/jedema/checking.php on line 3 because your code is missing ) after if(true

Comment: @pregmatch, this isn't the topic of my question. I want to detect this syntax to report it.

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand you correctly.

Comment: I edited the title of your question, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: that's a pretty good edit. Thanks Andras Deak !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) for such needs. 
An example:

If I have a script that returns a non-zero return code and prints something on stderr like this (named `test_external_command.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
>&2 echo "my Error on STDERR!"
exit 255
```

And I want to have the stderr in  a variable I can use the `sh` module in a Python script as follows (named `checker.py`):

```
import sh

def main():
    my_cmd = sh.Command('/path/to/test_external_command.sh')
    try:
        my_cmd()
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode_255 as e:
        print 'expected return code'
        print 'STDERR was: {}'.format(e.stderr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can see that the stderr is saved in `sh.ErrorReturnCode_255` as the `stderr` attribute.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use `subprocess.Popen`, its returns tuple of output and error

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['php','-l', path_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = child.communicate()
```

Comment: Quoting from http://stackoverflow.com/a/8984492/5388440:
Use script_response = subprocess.check_output(["php", "/path/to/your/script.php"]) instead.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but I can't display output and error. I add the new **check_php_file** function that I tried and print(sortie) display nothing, it is the same behavior for print(error).