# ldconfig returns 255 exit code

Tags: linux

When run ldconfig -p returned exit code 255, Anybody know that means?

RAN: `/usr/sbin/ldconfig -p`

STDOUT:

STDERR:

Answer (score -1):

use a simple script to verify that the script is being called, and then make sure to add an exit code

Comment: sh.ErrorReturnCode_255: this is the result returned when execute the script

Comment: Try adding a shebang to the top of your script:

like #! /bin/bash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299398/get-all-output-of-bash-command-in-python  you may see this solution